# How to Save iterable value to a text file and then upload it to google drive with Flutter(Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api

I want to save the value **data1** which contains iterable value of **CallLog.get()** to **data1.txt** file. I want to know that, how to upload the **data1.txt** file to google drive. The reason to save the value **data1** is to upload it to google drive. Here is the code:

```
class Data {
  Future<Iterable<CallLogEntry>> data1 = CallLog.get();
  Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    // For your reference print the AppDoc directory
    print(directory.path);
    return directory.path;
  }

  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/data1.txt');
  }

  Future<File> writeContent() async {
    final file = await _localFile;
    // Write the file
    return file.writeAsString('$data1');
  }

  Future<String> readcontent() async {
  try {
    final file = await _localFile;
    // Read the file
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    return contents;
  } catch (e) {
    // If there is an error reading, return a default String
    return 'Error';
  }
}
```

And after upload this, how can I access the **data1.txt** and show the call logs from **data1.txt** to a **ListView**. I have created a Listview to show this but it shows me an error. Here is the error:

> Class 'String' has no instance method 'toList'. Receiver: "Error"
>   Tried calling: toList()

Here is the code of my ListView:

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: Data().readcontent(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

                    List<CallLogEntry> entries = snapshot.data.toList();
                    return Scrollbar(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          var entry = entries[index];
                          var mono = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'monospace');
                          return Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Divider(),
                              Text('NUMBER   : ${entry.number}', style: mono),
                              Text('NAME     : ${entry.name}', style: mono),
                              Text('TYPE     : ${entry.callType}', style: mono),
                              Text(
                                  'DATE     : ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(entry.timestamp)}',
                                  style: mono),
                              Text('DURATION :  ${entry.duration}',
                                  style: mono),
                            ],
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          );
                        },
                        itemCount: entries.length,
                      ),
                    );
                  })
```